# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Drush commands not working - DDEV vanilla Drupal 8 install

Tags: drush, ddev

Just created a new Drupal 8 install using ddev, however, I'm having issues with drush. Whenever I run the command `drush cr` it returns the error:

```
 [error]  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

If I run the command `drush en admin_toolbar` with the `--debug` flag it returns the error:

`Executing: mysql --defaults-file=/private/tmp/drush_ty1hL4 --database=db --host=db --port=3306 --silent  < /private/tmp/drush_OSFtCb
  ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (0)`

`[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command pm:enable was not found. Drush was unable to query the database.`

The only solutions I was able to find in regards to this issue was changing `host` in settings.php from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` but since the settings.php file was generated by ddev during configuration, `host` is actually `db` and changing it to anything causes the site to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to run drush in recent versions of ddev.

The way most likely to work is to run drush commands inside the container.

`ddev ssh` and `drush cr`
or
`ddev exec drush cr`

You *can* also run drush on the host with ddev. If you're in the project directory and have drush 8 installed on the host, commands like `drush sql-cli` and `drush uli` "just work". Your mileage may vary.

There are a few things to note about drush usage in general though, especially with Drupal 8 and drush 9+:

- drush 9+ can never be installed globally, it's always installed per-project using composer.
- As recommended by the drush project, the global /usr/local/bin/drush inside the container is actually "drush launcher". It first attempts to use the site-local composer-installed drush. If that doesn't exist or can't be found, drush launcher will use /usr/local/bin/drush8, the global installation of drush 8 inside the container.
- I definitely know very experienced and famous Drupal 8 developers who never rely on drush launcher, they'll run drush commands like `vendor/bin/drush sql-cli` inside the container (or `ddev exec /var/www/html/vendor/bin/drush sql-cli` on the host) to get the exact site-local drush they want.

Comment: I found some more information on this here: https://phase2.github.io/devtools/common-tasks/ssh-into-a-container/

Comment: `ddev exec` is just a wrapper on `docker exec`, but it does all the lifting for you. Note that on a host system that's properly set up with drush 8, many drush commands also work on the host, if executed within the project directory. I'll edit the answer to reflect this.